# A change to a LibreOffice style does not get applied to the document?

Tags: libreoffice, styles

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong:

I have a text document written in LibreOffice Writer (v6.0.4.2, German). The document uses only basic styles - Title, Heading 1, Text Block.

Now I would expect that changing one of these styles would actually become visible in the document, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

As an example, I want to change the font size of the "Title" style. If I place the cursor somewhere in the title of my document, the style select correctly shows "Title". I then open the style properties, where "Title" is the selected style. When I change the font size here, the font size under the cursor changes, but the existing text remains as is.

Note that I'm aware that I can select the title and change the font size, but that doesn't work if I want to change the font size of all headings at once. So what am I missing?

Comment: I just tested this with LO 6.0.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and it works as expected. I edited the style in 2 ways: either right-click on an instance of the style and select **Styles** -> **Edit Style...**; or, regardless of the cursor position, from the menu bar click on **Styles** -> **Manage Styles** (F11) to bring up the _Styles and Formatting_ sidebar, then right-click on the appropriate entry and select **Modify...**. In either case all instances of the Style are changed. If I use the style drop-downs in the menu bar, only the selection or the word at the cursor position is changed.

Comment: Mmh. That does indeed work. However, when in the Style Manager, I click on the wrench icon for the style properties, and change the font size there in the side bar, (not in the dialog that pops up under Modify...), it does not work. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Looking at the official manual (Writer Guide), I just realize that the sidebar does not show the properties of the selected style, but rather the properties of the text, which includes a style. However, changing the font size from here would only apply a direct format to the selected or entered text. Confusing.

Comment: It seems that using that icon makes the same changes as using the style drop-downs in the menu bar, affecting the current selection or word. Its effects are similar to right-clicking and selecting **Character...**, though with a different dialogue.

Comment: LibreOffice 6.4.6.2 is showing the same behaviour: I edit a style and AutoUpdate is selected, but nothing gets applied to all concerned portions of my document. Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you try my humble solution, please first check that in the window where you edit your styles, in the "Organizer" tab, that "AutoUpdate" ist ticked.

In my document I found a potential problem (caused by a history of exports and importing) and it helped me fix this. It might help you or not, depending on your situation:

Select a good portion of your document, then right-click and select "Clear Direct Formatting". You might observe that immediatly, your style is being "applied".

As you wrote in your question, the style was assigned all the time, but some accidental manipulation made LibreOffice think, that you wanted a certain part in a specific format and used that for overruling the assigned style.

I tried selecting my entire document of some 80 pages to fix this with on click, but then the option was not available on right-click. You need to find out, how much you can select at any time, to be efficient.

Comment: "Clear Direct Formatting" was the key element for me, thanks!