# LibreOffice Writer: Reset formatting to the current style?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, styles

I have a chunk of text that is set to some style "Section Title". I messed with some settings in that chunk of text (e.g. font, line spacing), and now the text no longer matches what is in the style.

I want to reset the text to the settings defined in the style "Section Title", discarding all other formatting.

I don't see an option to do this in LibreOffice Writer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [A change to a LibreOffice style does not get applied to the document?](https://superuser.com/q/1374459/337511), right after posting my question.

The solution is to highlight the affected text, right-click, and select "Clear Direct Formatting" in the menu. It is also in the Format menu. See: https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/shared/01/05010000.html

> Direct formatting is formatting that you applied without using styles, such as setting bold typeface by clicking the Bold icon.

It looks like "direct formatting" is a general term used in LibreOffice, for text formatting that is applied separately from a style.